# Does anyone have codes that would solve the multi-period Kyle model?

Tags: programming, market-microstructure, models, codes

Whenever I begin working on something new, I like to find existing examples of how things are done so that I can double check at least the basics before moving on to more complicated problems.

I am not familiar with how people would go about solving for parameter values in the system of recursive equations that define parameter values across time in the multi-period Kyle (1985) model, so I'd like to know if anyone here has a working code to do it. Since it's a well known model and the basis of a lot of work, I'm just trying having to clumsily reinvent the wheel here.

The code can be written in MATLAB, R or Python. It's not a problem. Or, short of a code, if someone had a detailed algorithm to do it, it could work too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but maybe it can help: https://mingze-gao.com/measures/kyleslambda/

Comment: @amdopt It's not what I was looking for, but it is nonetheless interesting. I managed to find an answer to my question late last night. Dale Rosenthal has codes from an R/Finance presentation on his website and he solves the multi-period model of Kyle. I also wrote code for the single period case and theoretical values concur with simulated values, so everything is in order right now. Thanks for the reference nonetheless.

Comment: I figured as much.  It was something I knew of so I figured I would pass it along to you